# Single word for time and place of birth

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single English word that describes the geographic place and time of a person's birth? 
 My real question is how do I express where I was born at a particular time in history with a single word.

Comment: Why would you want or need to do this?

Comment: There are some specific examples, such as *He was an **Elizibethan**. But this merely an example of, and not a a generic term for the concept.

Comment: Besides any answer below, I add another example, which could be "Nativity".  Of course, that's only if you are Jesus Christ.  However, the could be a useful example, depending on what your goal is.  For example, if you're writing fiction, you could name an event after a person's birth if that person was supposedly sufficiently important (similar to how the midnight of January 1, 1970, which Unix users have named "epoch", though that particular example doesn't mention the place).

Comment: 'Birth coordinates' is what they use, translated, in European languages, but not really in English.

Comment: [vital statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vital_statistics_(government_records)) refers to data about birth, marriage, death, and other life events, as recorded by public bodies. It isn't an exact match but might do as a general term for such data.

Comment: Here we go again today; There's another question re how to say time and place of a meeting in one word. This is just silly. Anything that involves time and place will involve those two things.

Comment: @Lambie, except that some people think of the world as four-dimensional, and, consequently, of the spatiotemporal coordinates of something as one 'thing'.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any such word. Natal time and Natal place are two different elements and not often combined.  Only horoscopes use both that I know of, and if they have one term it might well be considered jargon.

Answer (score 1):

No. They are two different concepts and cannot be described with a single word. The shortest can be

> I was born on 12/12/1800 in Oxford.

Answer (score 1):

Setting seems to be a general term used to specify both time and place, but not specifically for birth.

Comment: I don't think Setting defines a time at all. And usually it is just describing what is *in* the location, not where it is.  For example, the "setting" for a scene in a play tells where the furniture is, not its GPS location.

Comment: That's why I said "seems to" and "general". Setting does take into account a both time and place. There is no one-word phrase that exactly depicts time to the millisecond and place to the degree, minute, and second.

Answer (score 0):

In English, following an olde tradition we use an [ISO 8601 timestamp with a UTC timezone offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).  That indicates the time and date, and narrows your birthplace down to one timezone, which is good enough for most uses. This also has the advantage of reducing North-South discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

Origin.  My origin was Germany on such-and-such a date.  It does tend to strongly suggest a location, more than it does time.  For time, it may need a little help (like the word "on", as shown, or "at"), but if you mention a time, people will understand you mean your birth time because of the word "origin".

Comment: 'Origin' only refers to place.

Comment: as the OP wants a term that also refers to time

Answer (score -1):

Following on from earlier contributions, I suggest 'natality.'

Comment: No. *natality* means *birthrate*, not time and place.

Comment: Agreed, just as 'mortality' means death rate. Still, I am reminded of my own mortality.

Comment: This is effectively a **proposal** that the word be used in a new way; the question asks whether there **is** a word that already has that meaning.